# Windows 10 refuses to respect network metric

Tags: windows-10, networking

**TL;DR;**
Windows 10

Two network 1 using Ethernet cable the other using Wi-Fi

Wi-fi has access to internet the cable is only for local transfers

Windows is incapable to respect the manually set metrics and even resets them every once in a while and wrongfully assumes that the local network IS the network offering a gateway to Internet when, no, it's actually not the case the Wi-Fi IS the network to access to Internet

Of course, if I leave everything in automatic Windows behaves badly too and refuses to see that Wifi is the right network to access Internet.

**Technical setup**
I have two networks on my PC which is running Windows 10 Pro (up to date).

- One (N1) is fully local, i.e. no internet access, uses ethernet
  cable. On the Screenshot N1 is called Wi-Fi (It's A Trap 3 5G)
- Second (N2) is wifi, connected to internet. On the screenshot N2 is called Ethernet (Notreblabla)

[image: My two networks]

N1 is manually set to a metric of 600.
N2 is manually set to a metric of 1

And, as you can see on the screenshot below the N1's metric is correctly set to 600
[image: N1 metric]

While N2's metric is set to 1 as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: N2 metric]

**The problem starts here**

And instead of seeing the Wi-Fi icon, I see this icon:
[image: local network icon]

So when this happens I turn off the local network (N1) (right click disable) -> and of course then I have access to internet and the Wi-Fi icon shows up.

By doing this (disabling N1), it apparently also...resets the metric to "automatic", even if the network (N1) is disabled and if re-enable the network (N1) now we have another unwanted behavior -> my manual set metrics have been discarded and Windows ASSUMES that N1 is the "best" network and REFUSES to access internet through the Wi-Fi.

So, yep, if anyone knows what's going on.
It's a fairly simple setup, there's no fancy or complex devices or tweaks

Comment: Have you rebooted after changing the metrics? Have you also set the metrics metrics for IPv6?

Comment: The metric is irrelevant to what you are trying to do. Metrics are used to determine which path to use if they lead to the same destination, but your paths do not. Manipulate the routing table instead.